# Parsing default arguments in functions without executing the them

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, default-arguments

I need to pass a function (without calling it) to another function, but I need to specify a different value for a default argument.

For example:

```
def func_a(input, default_arg=True):
    pass

def func_b(function):
    pass

func_b(func_a(default_arg=False))
```

This, however, *calls* `func_a()` and passes the result to `func_b()`.

How do I set `default_arg=False` without executing `func_a`?

Comment: Will `func_b` only ever pass `input` when it calls `func_a`, or do you also need to handle the possibility of `func_b` overriding `default_arg` too. BTW, `input` is not a good choice of variable name as it shadows the built-in `input` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda function. Like this:

```
func_b(lambda input: func_a(input, default_arg=False))
```

In `func_b` you will have a callable `function` which accepts argument input and executes `func_a` with previously specified `default_arg` argument.

---

Thanks to [cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736308/cdarke) for suggest this way:

```py
from functools import partial, wraps

def func_wrapper(f, **kwargs):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(input):
        return f(input, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

```
func_b(func_wrapper(func_a, default_arg=False))
```

Comment: `lambda`s don't have `__name__` or `__doc__` attributes.   We don't know if either of those is required by `func_b`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

func_b(partial(func_a, default_arg=False))
```

The `partial()` object is a callable too, when called it'll apply the arguments you gave it to the first argument.

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def func_a(input, default_arg=True):
...     print('func_a() called with {!r}, and default_arg={!r}'.format(input, default_arg))
...
>>> def func_b(function):
...     print('Calling the function')
...     function('Foo bar')
...
>>> func_b(partial(func_a, default_arg=False))
Calling the function
func_a() called with 'Foo bar', and default_arg=False
```

Comment: `partial` objects don't have  `__name__` or __doc__` attributes.  We don't know if that would be an issue, but it can be alleviated using `functools.update_wrapper()`.

Comment: @cdarke: sure, you can add additional attributes to the `partial()` instance; they won't be used in the `repr()` output of the object, though.